# Como remover notação científica no eixo-y usando matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Ao gerar um gráfico utlizando a biblioteca `matplotlib` em linguagem Python no Jupyter Notebook, percebi que os dados apresentados nele estavam "reduzidos" (acho que seria esse o termo) e com uma nomenclatura esquisita em cima do eixo Y (`le7`).
Os dados gerados foram entre 100.000 e 1.000.000 para realizar testes de estudo sobre a biblioteca, visto que sou iniciante. Embaixo segue o gráfico gerado:

[image: Gráfico gerado]

Teria como eu fazer com que os "números reduzidos" ficassem com seus valores "normais"? O que seria essa nomenclatura `le7`? Estou utilizando a biblioteca `sqlite3`, extraindo informações de um banco de dados de um simples arquivo. Abaixo segue o código que foi feito para gerar o gráfico:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sqlite3 import *

conn = connect('C:\\Users\\lucas\\Documents\\Bancos\\empresas.db')
c = conn.cursor()

a = c.execute("SELECT empresa, SUM(acoes) FROM empresas GROUP BY empresa;")

empresa = []
acao = []

for i in a:
    empresa.append(i[0])
    acao.append(i[1])
    
plt.xlabel('Empresas')
plt.ylabel('Ações')

plt.bar(empresa,acao)
plt.show()
```

Para saber sobre os valores, os dados que foram retornados no banco foram estes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1e7` está indicando que a escala está em dezenas de milhões (10^7). Em geral, é recomendável passar a escala para milhões (10^6) ou milhares (10^3) para facilitar a leitura do gráfico. Mas se quiser manter na forma original basta usar o método `plt.ticklabel_format`:

```py
plt.xlabel('Empresas')
plt.ylabel('Ações')
plt.bar(empresa,acao)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado! Saberias me dizer também como faço para colocar os valores encima de cada barra do gráfico de barras? Grato!

Comment: Você vai precisar usar `plt.annotate`. Veja se essa resposta responde à sua pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360662/mostrar-valor-dentro-de-uma-barra-com-matplotlib Em caso negativo, abra uma nova questão